# mysql check if value exist in group

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by, aggregate

I have a table called `votes` with columns `id`, `image_id`, `user_id` and `time`.

How can I add a bool in the result for if a specific `user_id` is one of the votes for each `image_id`?

```
SELECT image_id,
count(image_id) as vote_count
FROM votes
GROUP BY image_id 
ORDER BY vote_count DESC
```

I have tried `if(user_id = 18, 1, 0) as have_voted` but it does not work for each `image_id`.

Comment: I'm not really understanding what you are trying to gather. Since you are aggregating by image id, you lose the specific rows from your user id. It sounds like using an 'IN' clause might be what you want?

Comment: I needed the amount of votes and know if the current user have voted or not for each image.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

What about summing all the rows where the `user_id` is the one you want, and checking if this sum is greater than 0?

```
SELECT image_id,
count(image_id) as vote_count,
SUM(IF(user_id = 18,1,0)) > 0 AS hasUser18
FROM votes
GROUP BY image_id 
ORDER BY vote_count DESC
```

Comment: A much simpler expression is `max(user_id = 1)`.

Comment: thanks, this works as I wanted. `sum(user_id = 1)` and `max(user_id = 1)` did too

Comment: I would be interested to see the performance of `SUM(IF(user_id = 18,1,0))` vs `sum(user_id = 1)` vs `max(user_id = 1)`